# How to use "when" correctly as a conjunction

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> When I will go, I will talk to you.

I mean to ask whether or not we use *will* with *when* in this kind of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'when' to indicate a context in the future, you don't use 'will.' 'Will' becomes redundant, since it is understood that you're talking about the future.

> When I finish my work, I will call you.

Answer (score 0):

> When I go, I will talk to you.

When using "when" the second action must happen after the first, so the tense of the first is not going to be future.